# What is the filter or hook to add admin controls to posts on the front end?

Tags: posts, filters, hooks, templates

What is the filter or hook that would allow me to add a custom control (an action link) for admins next to "Edit" on posts on the front end? I want to give admins the option of carrying out an action on a post just as they might click edit while browsing their blog.

I've browsed quite a lot of Google search results and some of the WordPress action listings without identifying what it is I need to use. It may very well be staring me in the face so I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

I am, of course, assuming that such a hook/filter exists - if that's not the case is there another approach that I can explore?

Comment: Have you tried to check the WP source? Usually `grep`ping some of the parts helps me identify the relevant part quickly and you'll directly see all actions/filters applied there.

Comment: This is typically a theme-specific implementation and not something you can simply add with a WP Filter.  There may be a filter provided with the theme you're using, you'll need to research the docs of the theme or contact them.

Comment: The closest you could get is using the `the_content` or `the_excerpt` hooks to add a link to those, but whether that's anywhere near the theme's edit link is entirely theme specific.